# Maximum independent set relaxation and its dual

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, linear-programming, integer-programming

The integer program for the independent set is given by

\begin{align*}
&\max\sum_{v\in V}x_v\\
&\text{s.b.t } x_u+x_v\leq 1, \text{ for all }\{u,v\}\in E\\
&\quad\quad \  x_v\in\{0,1\}, \text{ for all }v\in V
\end{align*}

So, the relaxation should be $0\leq x_v\leq 1$. However, many write $x_v\geq 0$, probably because $x_u+x_v\leq 1$ implies that $x_u,x_v\leq 1$ for all $\{u,v\}\in E$. However, if there are isolated vertices then the LP relaxation is unbounded which feels a bit wrong.

For the dual program, adding $x_i\leq 1$ causes introducing the additional dual variable $y_v$ resulting
\begin{align*}
&\min\sum_{e\in E}y_{e}+\sum_{v\in V}y_i\\
&\text{s.b.t } \sum_{e\in E\colon v\in e} y_{e}\geq 1 &\text{for all }v\in V\\
& &y_e\geq 0, \text{ for all }e\in E\\
& &y_v\geq 1, \text{ for all }v\in E
\end{align*}
However, it complicates the deriving that the dual of the maximum independent set is the minimum edge cover, [as derived here (at Problem 3)](https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Eamenta/w04/hw4_sol.pdf).

If you can spot an error, or explain how it makes sense it will be helpful.

Comment: Like I think it is a pretty stupid case, and one can solve the Max Indep. set problem on the non-isolated vertices and then add the isolated ones. But I think that something should be said or just to add a premise that the graph is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the dual objective: $y_i$ versus $y_v$

Your dual constraint needs to include the new dual variable.

The lower bound on the new dual variable should be $0$ instead of $1$.

Also, it would be less confusing to give the new dual variable a new name because you are already using $y$.

Comment: Note that if $M$ is the incident matrix then the primal is maximum  $1^T x$ subject to $\begin{pmatrix}M^T\\I\end{pmatrix}x\leq 1$ and translating to the dual we need to minimize $1^T y$ subject to $\begin{pmatrix}M\\I\end{pmatrix}y\geq 1$ so the $I y\geq 1$ translates to $y_v\geq 1$. We also have that for all $y_v,y_e\geq 0$ due to the primal constraints $\begin{pmatrix}M^T\\I\end{pmatrix}\leq 1$

Comment: You did not transpose correctly.  It should instead be $(M\quad I)$.

Comment: It is still remains $y_v\geq 1$, doesn't it?

Comment: No, the lower bound is $y_v \ge 0$, and $+y_v$ appears on the LHS of the dual constraint.  The $I$ in the dual constraints corresponds to the coefficients of $y_v$ in the same constraints as $y_e$.

Comment: Thanks(below I detail how I convince myself), I think **my main question was how to settle down that it ruins the interoperability of the dual problem as an edge cover!**

Let's say we have two vertices and one edge then the primal constraints are $x_1+x_2\leq 1$, and $x_1,x_2\leq 1$ and non-negativity constrains $x_1,x_2\geq 0$.
The dual introduce the variables $y_{12},y_1,y_2\geq 0$ with constraints $y_{12}+y_1\geq 1, y_{12}+y_2\geq 1$.  thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct dual for that small example.  To help understand, I recommend extending that example to include an isolated node $3$.

Comment: Hint: For an isolated node $v$, you can think of the dual variable $y_v$ as being associated with a self-loop from $v$ to $v$, and doing so preserves the edge cover interpretation.